# Can we get the line graph of the $3D$ cube as a Cayley graph?

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, graph-theory, finite-groups, cayley-graphs

Given a graph $G=(V,E)$, the line graph of $G$ is a graph $\Gamma$ whose vertices are $E$ (the edges of $G$) and in $\Gamma$, two vertices $e_1,e_2$ are connected if, as edges in $G$, they share an endpoint.

Now let $G$ be the $3D$ cube graph. It has $8$ vertices, $12$ edges and it is $3$-regular. It is actually the Cayley graph of $\mathbb{Z}_2^3$ with generators $(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)$.

Let $\Gamma$ be the line graph of this $G$. Then $\Gamma$ has $12$ vertices and it is $4$-regular and highly symmetric.

> Is $\Gamma$ the Cayley graph of some group $H$ (of order $12$) with a symmetric set of generator $S \subset H$ ($|S|=4$)?

(by a *symmetric* set I mean that $x\in S \Rightarrow x^{-1}\in S$, making the Cayley graph undirected).

Comment: There are only 5 groups of order 12 (up to isomorphism). Have you tried any of them on for size?

Comment: @Gerry: I looked in [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_small_groups), but it is not just a matter of choosing the group, but also choosing the generators. So, although I didn't see how to do it, I might have chosen the generators in the wrong way.

Comment: @user1729: I think I need to choose $4$ generators of of group of size $12$, because every edge is adjacent to 4 other.

Comment: @Alex Sorry, I meant four, and then I realised that it should be $4/2=2$, or there are generators of order two...

Comment: OK, but maybe you can rule out some of the groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't checked this, but try $H=A_4$, with $S=\{g,h,g^{-1},h^{-1}\}$ where $g=(1,2,3)$ and $h=(2,3,4)$. So vertices of the cube are labelled alternately with $g$ and $h$, and multiplication of an element (egde) by a generator (vertex) corresponds to rotating the edge clockwise round that vertex (or anticlockwise for multiplication by the inverse).

Comment: Do you mean $H=A_4$?

Comment: Indeed I do. Will edit.

Comment: I have references to support this: I think my line graph is [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuboctahedron) which can be found as this Cayley Graph [here](http://www.weddslist.com/groups/cayley-plat/)

Answer (score 0):

C.Hagemeyer & R.Scott, On Groups with Cayley Graph Isomorphic to a Cube. Communications in Algebra, v.42, No.4, 2014, pp.1484-1495.